# How to achieve string aggregation in a query in oracle 9i?

Tags: oracle, aggregation, oracle9i

How to achieve string aggregation in a query in oracle 9i ?

LISTAGG wont work with oracle 9i

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php):-

One approach is to write a specific function to solve the problems.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_employees (p_deptno  in  emp.deptno%TYPE)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_text  VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE deptno = p_deptno) LOOP
    l_text := l_text || ',' || cur_rec.ename;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN LTRIM(l_text, ',');
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS
```

The function can then be incorporated into a query as follows.

```
COLUMN employees FORMAT A50

SELECT e.deptno,
       get_employees(e.deptno) AS employees
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT deptno
        FROM   emp) e;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 SMITH,JONES,SCOTT,ADAMS,FORD
        30 ALLEN,WARD,MARTIN,BLAKE,TURNER,JAMES
```